# ListView Adapter Crashes Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, crash, adapter

As in the subcjet. When I comment `listView.setAdapter(adapter);` it just shows another activity:

This is whole onCreate:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista__klas);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        klasy = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.klasy);

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista_klas);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_lista__klas);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

And here log from logcat when I press button which starts this activity:

```
11-20 13:14:53.085    1494-1780/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START {cmp=pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta/.Lista_Klas} from pid 3975
11-20 13:14:53.335    3975-3975/pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-20 13:14:53.335    3975-3975/pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a521f8)
11-20 13:14:53.345    3975-3975/pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta/pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta.Lista_Klas}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta.Lista_Klas.onCreate(Lista_Klas.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 13:14:53.355    1494-1675/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta/.Lista_Klas
11-20 13:14:53.355    1494-1675/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta/.MainActivity
11-20 13:14:53.865    1494-1509/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40ef3f48 pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta/.Lista_Klas}
11-20 13:14:54.065    3215-3215/com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet W/Adreno200-EGLSUB﹕ SetSwapInterval() interval: 0 not set
11-20 13:14:54.105    1494-1506/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ No longer want com.android.keychain (pid 3950): hidden #16
11-20 13:15:04.105    1494-1509/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{40ebf3c0 pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta/.MainActivity}
11-20 13:15:04.105    1494-1509/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{40ef3f48 pl.krasiniak.krachapp_beta/.Lista_Klas}
```

I'm sure array isn't empty. Thank you for answers, greetings :)

Comment: Is the context null? oder another value?

Comment: you forgot to pass "klasy" array in adapter. :)

Comment: did you do like this===> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_lista__klas,klasy);

Comment: what do you mean? when I write `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_lista__klas);` it makes no diffrence

Comment: but from where you add klasy array to adapter?

Comment: @tuksiarz: you are not passing the array data to adapter. Here adapter helping your listview to bind data in listview. But here, you forgot the main point. you haven't provided any data to adapter. No it is givving error as nothing to display in listview

Comment: @RipalTamboli You can create an adapater without giving it any data. It just has an empty array. This is no problem. It shows an empty list. It won't crash because of this.

Comment: @tuksiarz: in "new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_lista__klas);" , does your layout has TextView??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code cannot be correct:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista__klas);

// ...

ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista_klas);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_lista__klas);
```

The same layout is used for both content view and array adapter. When the [two-argument constructor of `ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) is used, the resource id must resolve to a single `TextView`. The `findViewById()` call implies it is a more complex layout with a `ListView`.

If I understand your intention correctly, do the following:

- Make sure `activity_list__klas` contains a `ListView` with the specified id `lista_klas` so that the `findViewById()` returns non-`null`.
- Change the layout resource id of the adapter constructor to a resource file that contains a single `TextView` that represents your list row. Or change to another constructor overload that allows you to specify the `TextView`s where array items are mapped.
- Provide some data to the adapter to actually show something.

Comment: This is the solution! I forgot about your second point. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add third parameter

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.activity_lista__klas,klasy);
```

If this did not work. Please paste your layout file too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your problem is here:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista_klas);
```

Check that you have a `ListView` with this ID and that `listView` is not null.

Also, when you create the adapter you need to pass the `ArrayAdapter` a layout file that contains a single `TextView` to use to display each list item. You've passed the same layout that you've used in `setContentView` which (I assume) is the complete layout for your activity.

Comment: maybe you're right becouse other solutions doesn't work. I'm new with Placeholder (I just have migrated form Eclipse to Android Studio) and I don't know if I will put ListView in fragment_lista_klas.xml not in activity_lista_klas.xml will it be ok?

Comment: Sorry, don't really understand your comment.